# How can I make bash terminal to beep when its output screen changes?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, beep

I am using gnome-terminal. 
Is it possible to make it(or any other terminal) beep whenever its output screen changes (like some new output line came)?

I want it for only one particular window.

Comment: You should probably ask this on Super User, since it's not programming-related.

Comment: Oh I didn't know. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly of use:

The GNU `screen` program has features for monitoring background windows for activity as well as inactivity.

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Monitor

Something called lTerm has "tabs with activity alerts"

http://lterm.sourceforge.net/

But at this point I'm turning into a meta search engine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ./myprogram | sed 's/$/\a/'
```

#### for example

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done | sed 's/$/\a/'
```